# Make a table cell editable by using a button

Tags: jquery, html

Can anyone help me with this one. I'm trying to make a table cell (`td` column) editable by using a button. I don't have any knowledge of jquery.

I'm trying this one:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"></a></li>
     <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2"></a></li>
    <button href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button" id="btninfo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
     </ul>

        <table border="0" style="width: 100%; font-size:13px; margin-left: 30px">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
             <th style="width:30%">Birthday:</th>
             <td style="width:100%" contenteditable="false"><label></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th >Middle Name:</th>
            <td contenteditable="false"><label></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Course:</th>
            <td contenteditable="false"><label></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Status:</th>
            <td contenteditable="false"><label></label></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You will need to have knowledge - or gain knowledge - of jQuery//JavaScript if you want to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to learn through video tutorials and codes school. I guess self-study is quite hard. Btw, Thanks Mate

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `contenteditable` property of each `td` as true. Following is an example of doing this with jquery.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.glyphicon-pencil').click(function () {
    $('td').prop('contenteditable', true);
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/45vLfw90/)

---

**EDIT: Based on comments**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.glyphicon-pencil').closest('button').click(function () {
    if ($('td').attr('contenteditable') === 'false') {
        $('td').attr('contenteditable', true);
    } else {
        $('td').attr('contenteditable', false);
    }

  });
});
```

Updated [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/45vLfw90/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I more thing, do you have how to make the button also be the save making it unedited again?

Comment: Sorry, did'nt get you. You want to make the button uneditable on the click of same button or some other button?

Comment: Yes, On the same button too.